# How do i use socat as a proxy server?

Tags: socat

I'd like my .NET app to use a proxy which I know how to do except .net doesn't support sock4a/sock5. I know how to setup my app but, how do I setup socat to listen at as a TCP proxy on port 1234 and use the socks5 server at 127.0.0.1:5678?

It must forward all TCP connect. I had luck with privoxy earlier but that only supports http connections.

PS: I am on windows but the commands should be the same as linux

Comment: `socat` has a very complete man page.

Comment: @PierreCarrier i cant understand it. Also it doesnt explain the error messages i gotten and neither does google.

Comment: What protocols is the .NET application using? HTTP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't specify the destination host which you want to connect to through the SOCKS server. I've used `google.com` on port 80 in this example.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:google.com:80,socksport=5678
```

The `TCP-LISTEN` address is the port to listen on for connections from the .NET application. `1234` is obviously the port number, and the `fork` option allows multiple connections to be made. The `SOCKS4A` address is the SOCKS server and destination host to connect to. (If you don't want the SOCKS server to do DNS resolution change `SOCKS4A` to `SOCKS4`.) `127.0.0.1` is the address of the SOCKS server, and the `socksport` option specifies the port of the SOCKS server. `google.com:80` is the destination host and port to ask the SOCKS server to connect to.

Comment: This is the part thats confusing me. My .NET app should be able to visit google, yahoo, SO or any other site. Which is why it didnt make sense to set google.com:80 bc now it seems like no matter what site i want to visit it will always go to google? I want to say .NET use 127.0.0.1:1234, its a SOCKS proxy that sits at 127.0.0.1:5678 and it will let you go whereever you want. (dns resolution on the socks proxy). What is the command to do that?

Comment: @acidzombie24 In that case your app needs to understand that there's a proxy there and actually talk to the proxy. socat can't magically know where the app wants to connect to.

Comment: Thats fine and all but my app DOES know where to connect to. However how do i tell socat that info? I figured it out but w/o using socat. I wrote my own SOCKS code. It was time consuming :x

Comment: @acidzombie24 Your app knows, but it needs to *tell* the proxy that, which means that you need a protocol between the app and the proxy which can convey that information... like SOCKS.

Comment: You all have got it so wrong. OP wants socat to _be the socks server_, the .NET app needs to tell socat the host it wants to connect to. Yes, and it wants to do that. How do you get socat to BE the thing that listens to what the socks client wants to connect to? That is the question.